# Show HTML string as rendered page in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, textarea

In MVC4 Application, I have a HTML string where I am rendering the string in `Textarea` and it is showing as simple string.

Is there a way in MVC to render the HTML string as actual page through `iframe` or something ?

Comment: Why not render it within a `div` tag?

Comment: @AhsN, HTML string is full html with HTML and Body tags and internal css as well. I think that won't be good to show in DIV

Comment: use Html.Raw() method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope the answer will help you.

You can pass the HTML string to view through model. It will display the HTML string in the `textarea`

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult HTMLView()
{
    string result= "<HTML><BODY><DIV>Testing</DIV></BODY></HTML>";
    return View((object)result);
}
```

**View**

```
@model string
    <div>
        @Html.TextArea("html", @Model, new { id="htmlTextArea" })
    </div>
```